# How to proxy to PHP page without double regex?

Tags: nginx

The *location* where I try to *proxy_pass* to a PHP is not working,  state "404 Not Found".

```
server {
    server_name api-test.etc.etc;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/etc.etc.access_log;
    root /var/www/etc.etc/;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    # .....

    location ~ /v1\.json/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/(.+) {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000?f=uridisp_$1_$2&p_uri=$3&$args;
      # is working fine!
    }

    location ~ /v1\.html?/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/(.+) {
      # proxy_pass phpPage.php?f=uridisp_$1_$2&p_uri=$3&$args;
      # 404 Not Found
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
      proxy_pass phpPage.php?f=uridisp_$1_$2&p_uri=$3&$args;
      # 404 Not Found
    }
} # \server
```

---

As @Richard comment, I try also

```
    location ~ /v1\.html?/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/(.+) {
      rewrite
        ^/?v1\.html?/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/(.+)$
        /phpPage.php?f=uridisp_$1_$2&p_uri=$3&$args;
        break;
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
```

... and it **is working fine!**  Now the question is **how to avoid double regular expression?**  Is possible to express `fastcgi_pass` with the `/var/www/etc.etc/phpPage.php` directlelly?

Comment: You have `proxy_pass` and `fastcgi_pass` in the same `location` block. These are mutually exclusive. If the PHP is served by another server using `http` or `https`, use `proxy_pass`. If the PHP is a local file being executed using php_fpm, use `fastcgi_pass`. Assuming a working FastCGI configuration, you are probably missing `rewrite ^/v1\.html?/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/(.+)$ /phpPage.php?f=uridisp_$1_$2&p_uri=$3 break;`

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith thanks to the solution!  Now the question is about "how to avoid double regex"

Comment: You probably don't need a regex, you could use `location ^~ /v1.htm { ... }`

Comment: @RichardSmith, unfortunately my real life script have many locations at `# .....`, but you correct for simple cases.  The focus of the question is now on `fastcgi_pass` and its use in an exotic case.

Comment: What about `/v1(\.html|\.json)?/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)/(.+)` ?